# Dump data from django Feincms

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py, feincms

I'm using feincms in a django project and I want to use manage.py dumpdata but I get nothing:

```
python manage.py dumpdata feincms                 
[]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to dump the page data you need to run dumpdata on the page app. The page models live there, not in feincms:

```
 python manage.py dumpdata page
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know FeinCMS, but looking at the GitHub repo it seems that the `feincms` application only contains abstract models. If you want to dump the data, you'll need to find where the actual concrete models are, and dump that app.

Comment: actually, the Page model is not abstract, and lives in "feincms.module.page.models.Page" that looks like the still is feicms.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to use dumpdata all, but I should warn you: the more complex your application, the more likely it is that the dumpdata will miss something. If all else fails, try doing a dump directly from your database, rather than relying on Django.